# JAVA error in try catch block

Tags: java, enums, try-catch

I'm  a beginner to java , and i was doing a simple program having classes in different files and creating the objects. 
I have two files called `dataFile.java` ( for data a,b,c which will take input from keyboard with the help of method `getdata()` )
another file is called `classFile.java` which is used for using the data from the other class and printing the sum.
However im getting this error while compiling the `dataFile.java`

Code for the `dataFile.java` is as follows

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
class differentFile
{

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        int a,b,c; 
        try {
        void getdata(){
        a= Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
        b=Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
        c=Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
        }

     }
        catch(Exeption e) {
                System.out.println(" IO ERROR ");
                 }
}
```

and the error im finding is

```
dataFile.java:8: error: illegal start of type
    try {
    ^
dataFile.java:8: error: ';' expected
    try {
       ^
dataFile.java:17: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    catch(Exeption e) { 
    ^ 
dataFile.java:19: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        } 
        ^
4 errors
```

I'm not familiar with these errors and according to the textbook im using the syntax is correct. It would be greatfull if anyone helped me with this . Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try-catch` block must be present inside the method. You have started the `try` even before the method and then closed the method before having a `catch` clause for the `try` in the method. You need to re-arrange your code to something like this:

```
void getdata() {  // Method starts
    try { // try starts
        a = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
        b = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
        c = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
    } // try ends

    catch (Exeption e) { // catch for the try starts
        System.out.println(" IO ERROR ");
    } // catch ends
} // method ends
```

Comment: Sorry deleted the comment, confused with the error printing `IO Error` but of course it could also be an `NumberFormatException`

Comment: @user2310289 - No problem. I removed mine too! Let's clean this up :)

Comment: It worked ! i dint know that i have to use the try-catch inside a method . Is it always like that ?

Comment: @Sach106 - Yes. In java, you need to place almost all the statements(other than declaration statements and a few others) inside a method. They shouldn't be left hanging around in the class like that.

Answer (score 0):

Change as below:

```
void getdata() {
    try {
        a = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
        b = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
        c = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
    } catch (Exeption e) {
        System.out.println(" IO ERROR ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change like that

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;

class differentFile
{

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        int a,b,c; 
        try 
        {
             void getdata()
             {
                 a= Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
                 b=Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
                 c=Integer.valueOf(input.readLine()).intValue();
             } 
        }
        catch(Exeption e) 
        {
                System.out.println(" IO ERROR ");
        }

}
```

Comment: -1 because an explanation of what this code does or why it is your answer is missing.